# XML transform into XML

Tags: xml, xslt

I need to transform XML to XML. Actually it's already transforming but I bump into issue that I cant loop through some TAGs.
So I have this XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<PRODUCTS>

  <ITEM>
    <TITLE>Spintelė po praustuvu Formy</TITLE>
    <TECHNICAL_INFO><ul> <li>dydis (pxgxa): 80/100/120 x 55 x 22 cm</li> <li>medžiaga: MDF</li> <li>spalva: lakuota balta / ąžuolo arba riešuto imitacijos laminatas</li> <li><a href="img/pageflip/ravak-zaruka/13/" target="_blank" rel="noopener">Garantija: 5 metai</a></li> </ul> <p>Praustuvo spintelė Formy, montuojama po praustuvu Formy. Spintelė, kurios ilgis 80 cm, turi vieną stalčių, spintelė, kurios ilgis 100 ir 120 cm – turi su stalčius. Galite rinktis iš šių apdailos variantų: lakuotas baltas blizgus arba riešuto / ąžuolo laminatas. Korpusas tiekiamas surinktas, įskaitant ir montavimo komplektą (varžtai, vyriai, dangteliai). Spintelė tvirtinama prie sienos. Norint sukurti vientiso stiliaus vonios kambarį rekomenduojame praustuvo spintelę Formy derinti su kitais koncepcijos Formy gaminiais (praustuvu Formy I ir Formy II, veidrodžiu Formy, aukšta spintele SB Formy), RAVAK maišytuvais ir kitais gaminiais.</p></TECHNICAL_INFO>
    <IMAGES>
      <ITEM>
        <URL>https://www.ravak.cz/img/_/sd-formy.foto/sd-formy01-bila.jpg</URL>
      </ITEM>
      <ITEM>
        <URL>https://www.ravak.cz/img/_/sd-formy.foto/sd-formy01-orech.jpg</URL>
      </ITEM>
      </IMAGES>
    <GOODS>
      <ITEM>
        <TITLE>SD Formy 840 Juoda</TITLE>
        <COLOR>Juoda</COLOR>
        <EAN>85926260351111</EAN>
      </ITEM>
      <ITEM>
        <TITLE>SD Formy 9160 balta</TITLE>
        <COLOR>Balta</COLOR>
        <EAN>8592626035945</EAN>
      </ITEM>
     </GOODS> 
  </ITEM>
  <ITEM>
    <TITLE>Spintelė po praustuvu Formy 2000</TITLE>
    <TECHNICAL_INFO><ul> <li>dydis (pxgxa): 80/100/120 x 55 x 22 cm</li> <li>medžiaga: MDF</li> <li>spalva: lakuota balta / ąžuolo arba riešuto imitacijos laminatas</li> <li><a href="img/pageflip/ravak-zaruka/13/" target="_blank" rel="noopener">Garantija: 5 metai</a></li> </ul> <p>Praustuvo spintelė Formy, montuojama po praustuvu Formy. Spintelė, kurios ilgis 80 cm, turi vieną stalčių, spintelė, kurios ilgis 100 ir 120 cm – turi su stalčius. Galite rinktis iš šių apdailos variantų: lakuotas baltas blizgus arba riešuto / ąžuolo laminatas. Korpusas tiekiamas surinktas, įskaitant ir montavimo komplektą (varžtai, vyriai, dangteliai). Spintelė tvirtinama prie sienos. Norint sukurti vientiso stiliaus vonios kambarį rekomenduojame praustuvo spintelę Formy derinti su kitais koncepcijos Formy gaminiais (praustuvu Formy I ir Formy II, veidrodžiu Formy, aukšta spintele SB Formy), RAVAK maišytuvais ir kitais gaminiais.</p></TECHNICAL_INFO>
    <IMAGES>
      <ITEM>
        <URL>https://www.ravak.cz/img/_/sd-formy.foto/sd-formy01-bila2.jpg</URL>
      </ITEM>
      <ITEM>
        <URL>https://www.ravak.cz/img/_/sd-formy.foto/sd-formy01-orech2.jpg</URL>
      </ITEM>
      </IMAGES>
    <GOODS>
      <ITEM>
        <TITLE>SD Formy 810 Balta</TITLE>
        <COLOR>Juoda</COLOR>
        <EAN>85926260351111</EAN>
      </ITEM>
      <ITEM>
        <TITLE>SD Formy 900 balta</TITLE>
        <COLOR>Balta</COLOR>
        <EAN>8592626035789</EAN>
      </ITEM>
     </GOODS> 
  </ITEM>
</PRODUCTS>
```

And this is the XSLT which is transforming the XML:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"  
    xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl">  
   
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" encoding="utf-8" />  
   
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <root>
            <Products>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="PRODUCTS/ITEM"/>
            </Products>
        </root>
    </xsl:template>
    
    <xsl:template match="ITEM">
        <Product>
            <Product_id></Product_id>
            <SKU></SKU>
            <Barcode><xsl:apply-templates select="GOODS/ITEM/EAN"/></Barcode>
            <Name><xsl:value-of select="TITLE"/></Name>
            <Description><xsl:apply-templates select="TECHNICAL_INFO/ul/li"/></Description>
            <Images>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="IMAGES/ITEM/URL"/>
            </Images>
            <Units></Units>
            <Price></Price>
            <Currency>EUR</Currency>
            <Inventory_count></Inventory_count>
            <Note></Note>
            <Group1>STD.</Group1>
        </Product>
    </xsl:template>
    
   
    
    <xsl:template match="EAN">
        <ITEM><xsl:value-of select="."/></ITEM>
        
    </xsl:template>
    
    <xsl:template match="li">
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </xsl:template>
    
    <xsl:template match="URL">
        <Image><xsl:value-of select="."/></Image>
    </xsl:template>
    
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I get this result:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<root>
  <Products>
    <Product>
      <Product_id />
      <SKU />
      <Barcode>
        <ITEM>85926260351111</ITEM>
        <ITEM>8592626035945</ITEM>
      </Barcode>
      <Name>Spintelė po praustuvu Formy</Name>
      <Description>dydis (pxgxa): 80/100/120 x 55 x 22 cmmedžiaga: MDFspalva: lakuota balta / ąžuolo arba riešuto imitacijos laminatasGarantija: 5 metai</Description>
      <Images>
        <Image>https://www.ravak.cz/img/_/sd-formy.foto/sd-formy01-bila.jpg</Image>
        <Image>https://www.ravak.cz/img/_/sd-formy.foto/sd-formy01-orech.jpg</Image>
      </Images>
      <Units />
      <Price />
      <Currency>EUR</Currency>
      <Inventory_count />
      <Note />
      <Group1>STD.</Group1>
    </Product>
    <Product>
      <Product_id />
      <SKU />
      <Barcode>
        <ITEM>85926260351111</ITEM>
        <ITEM>8592626035789</ITEM>
      </Barcode>
      <Name>Spintelė po praustuvu Formy 2000</Name>
      <Description>dydis (pxgxa): 80/100/120 x 55 x 22 cmmedžiaga: MDFspalva: lakuota balta / ąžuolo arba riešuto imitacijos laminatasGarantija: 5 metai</Description>
      <Images>
        <Image>https://www.ravak.cz/img/_/sd-formy.foto/sd-formy01-bila2.jpg</Image>
        <Image>https://www.ravak.cz/img/_/sd-formy.foto/sd-formy01-orech2.jpg</Image>
      </Images>
      <Units />
      <Price />
      <Currency>EUR</Currency>
      <Inventory_count />
      <Note />
      <Group1>STD.</Group1>
    </Product>
  </Products>
</root>
```

But I need to get this result:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<root>
  <Products>
    <Product>
      <Product_id />
      <SKU />
      <Barcode>
        <ITEM>85926260351111</ITEM>
      </Barcode>
      <Name>Spintelė po praustuvu Formy</Name>
      <Description>dydis (pxgxa): 80/100/120 x 55 x 22 cmmedžiaga: MDFspalva: lakuota balta / ąžuolo arba riešuto imitacijos laminatasGarantija: 5 metai</Description>
      <Images>
        <Image>https://www.ravak.cz/img/_/sd-formy.foto/sd-formy01-bila.jpg</Image>
        <Image>https://www.ravak.cz/img/_/sd-formy.foto/sd-formy01-orech.jpg</Image>
      </Images>
      <Units />
      <Price />
      <Currency>EUR</Currency>
      <Inventory_count />
      <Note />
      <Group1>STD.</Group1>
    </Product>
    <Product>
      <Product_id />
      <SKU />
      <Barcode>
         <ITEM>8592626035945</ITEM>
      </Barcode>
      <Name>Spintelė po praustuvu Formy</Name>
      <Description>dydis (pxgxa): 80/100/120 x 55 x 22 cmmedžiaga: MDFspalva: lakuota balta / ąžuolo arba riešuto imitacijos laminatasGarantija: 5 metai</Description>
      <Images>
        <Image>https://www.ravak.cz/img/_/sd-formy.foto/sd-formy01-bila.jpg</Image>
        <Image>https://www.ravak.cz/img/_/sd-formy.foto/sd-formy01-orech.jpg</Image>
      </Images>
      <Units />
      <Price />
      <Currency>EUR</Currency>
      <Inventory_count />
      <Note />
      <Group1>STD.</Group1>
    </Product>
    <Product>
      <Product_id />
      <SKU />
      <Barcode>
        <ITEM>85926260351111</ITEM>
      </Barcode>
      <Name>Spintelė po praustuvu Formy 2000</Name>
      <Description>dydis (pxgxa): 80/100/120 x 55 x 22 cmmedžiaga: MDFspalva: lakuota balta / ąžuolo arba riešuto imitacijos laminatasGarantija: 5 metai</Description>
      <Images>
        <Image>https://www.ravak.cz/img/_/sd-formy.foto/sd-formy01-bila2.jpg</Image>
        <Image>https://www.ravak.cz/img/_/sd-formy.foto/sd-formy01-orech2.jpg</Image>
      </Images>
      <Units />
      <Price />
      <Currency>EUR</Currency>
      <Inventory_count />
      <Note />
      <Group1>STD.</Group1>
    </Product>
    <Product>
      <Product_id />
      <SKU />
      <Barcode>
        <ITEM>85926260351111</ITEM>
      </Barcode>
      <Name>Spintelė po praustuvu Formy 2000</Name>
      <Description>dydis (pxgxa): 80/100/120 x 55 x 22 cmmedžiaga: MDFspalva: lakuota balta / ąžuolo arba riešuto imitacijos laminatasGarantija: 5 metai</Description>
      <Images>
        <Image>https://www.ravak.cz/img/_/sd-formy.foto/sd-formy01-bila2.jpg</Image>
        <Image>https://www.ravak.cz/img/_/sd-formy.foto/sd-formy01-orech2.jpg</Image>
      </Images>
      <Units />
      <Price />
      <Currency>EUR</Currency>
      <Inventory_count />
      <Note />
      <Group1>STD.</Group1>
    </Product>
  </Products>
</root>
```

The main diference is that the EAN(barcode in result) need be looped each time with the same info from its PRODUCT.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAICT, you want to create a product for each variant (EAN), with all the common data of the parent item repeated.

This could be done by:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/PRODUCTS">
    <root>
        <Products>
            <xsl:for-each select="ITEM">
                <!-- parent item info -->
                <xsl:variable name="item-info">
                    <Name>
                        <xsl:value-of select="TITLE"/>
                    </Name>
                    <Description>
                        <xsl:apply-templates select="TECHNICAL_INFO/ul/li"/>
                    </Description>
                    <Images>
                        <xsl:apply-templates select="IMAGES/ITEM/URL"/>
                    </Images>
                </xsl:variable>
                <!-- a product for each variant -->
                <xsl:for-each select="GOODS/ITEM">
                    <Product>
                        <Product_id/>
                        <SKU/>
                        <Barcode>
                            <ITEM>
                                <xsl:value-of select="EAN"/>
                            </ITEM>
                        </Barcode>
                        <xsl:copy-of select="$item-info"/>
                        <Units/>
                        <Price/>
                        <Currency>EUR</Currency>
                        <Inventory_count/>
                        <Note/>
                        <Group1>STD.</Group1>
                    </Product>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </Products>
    </root>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="li">
    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
</xsl:template>
    
<xsl:template match="URL">
    <Image>
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </Image>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: This was really helpful. Thanks